# The limit of convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We have the following series $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{7^j(5j+1)}$$ If we use the ratio test,  we see that $\lim_{j\to \infty}\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}=\frac{1}{7}<1$. So this series is convergent. Now,does it mean that this series converges to $\frac{1}{7}$? I am confused as to what value should this series converges?

Comment: Ratio test can only give you an answer to whether a series converges or not. It cannot tell you its limit.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: So to what value this series converges? is there any way to know?

Comment: Do you know the solution? I just looked at Wolfram Alpha and judging from its output it seems that the solution is not something nice like $\frac{1}{7}$ and that such things like comparison of series, geometric series etc. will not suffice to get the limit.

Answer (score 2):

I shall not repeat what Matthias Klupsch commented.

Just develop the first terms $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{7^j(5j+1)}=\frac{1}{42}+\frac{1}{539}+\frac{1}{5488}+\frac{1}{50421}+\frac{1}{436982}+\frac{1}{3647119}+\cdots$$ As you can see, the sixth term is already very small and at this point the partial sum is $\frac{215870199}{8344608272} \approx 0.02586942274$ while the infinite sum would be $\approx 0.02586946132$

Comment: It is an approximate value(numerically) **NOT** analytically..Are there any analytic value?

Comment: There is an analytical value which is given (you would not like that !) $$\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{5},1;\frac{6}{5};\frac{1}{7}\right)-1$$ where appears the hypergeometric function.

Comment: It can also be written in terms of the Lerch Phi function.
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LerchPhi

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Thanks for that ! I missed it and the terrible thing is that I like very much the Lerch Phi function ! Cheers.